# Same Tree, Iterative Solution, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, stack, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I need to check if two given binary trees are the same. Here's an iterative solution that I wrote:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * function TreeNode(val) {
 *     this.val = val;
 *     this.left = this.right = null;
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {TreeNode} p
 * @param {TreeNode} q
 * @return {boolean}
 */

var isSameTree = function(p, q) {
    const nodePair = [p, q]
    const nodes = []

    if(p && q) nodes.push(nodePair) 
    else if (!p && !q) return true
    else return false

    while(nodes.length) {
        const lastNodePair = nodes.pop()

       if(
           (lastNodePair[0].val !== lastNodePair[1].val)
            || (lastNodePair[0].left && !lastNodePair[1].left)
            || (!lastNodePair[0].left && lastNodePair[1].left)
            || (lastNodePair[0].right && !lastNodePair[1].right)
            || (!lastNodePair[0].right && lastNodePair[1].right)
       ) return false

        if(lastNodePair[0].left && lastNodePair[1].left) {
            nodes.push([lastNodePair[0].left, lastNodePair[1].left])   
        }
        else if(lastNodePair[0].right && lastNodePair[1].right) {
            nodes.push([lastNodePair[0].right, lastNodePair[1].right])        
        }
    }
    return true
};
```

It passes 56 out of 57 test cases, but not this case, which is supposed to be `false`:

```
[390,255,2266,-273,337,1105,3440,-425,4113,null,null,600,1355,3241,4731,-488,-367,16,null,565,780,1311,1755,3075,3392,4725,4817,null,null,null,null,-187,152,395,null,728,977,1270,null,1611,1786,2991,3175,3286,null,164,null,null,4864,-252,-95,82,null,391,469,638,769,862,1045,1138,null,1460,1663,null,1838,2891,null,null,null,null,3296,3670,4381,null,4905,null,null,null,-58,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,734,null,843,958,null,null,null,1163,1445,1533,null,null,null,2111,2792,null,null,null,3493,3933,4302,4488,null,null,null,null,null,null,819,null,null,null,null,1216,null,null,1522,null,1889,2238,2558,2832,null,3519,3848,4090,4165,null,4404,4630,null,null,null,null,null,null,1885,2018,2199,null,2364,2678,null,null,null,3618,3751,null,4006,null,null,4246,null,null,4554,null,null,null,1936,null,null,null,null,2444,2642,2732,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,4253,null,null,null,null,2393,2461,null,null,null,null,4250,null,null,null,null,2537]

[390,255,2266,-273,337,1105,3440,-425,4113,null,null,600,1355,3241,4731,-488,-367,16,null,565,780,1311,1755,3075,3392,4725,4817,null,null,null,null,-187,152,395,null,728,977,1270,null,1611,1786,2991,3175,3286,null,164,null,null,4864,-252,-95,82,null,391,469,638,769,862,1045,1138,null,1460,1663,null,1838,2891,null,null,null,null,3296,3670,4381,null,4905,null,null,null,-58,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,734,null,843,958,null,null,null,1163,1445,1533,null,null,null,2111,2792,null,null,null,3493,3933,4302,4488,null,null,null,null,null,null,819,null,null,null,null,1216,null,null,1522,null,1889,2238,2558,2832,null,3519,3848,4090,4165,null,4404,4630,null,null,null,null,null,null,1885,2018,2199,null,2364,2678,null,null,null,3618,3751,null,4006,null,null,4246,null,null,4554,null,null,null,1936,null,null,null,null,2444,2642,2732,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,4253,null,null,null,null,2461,2393,null,null,null,null,4250,null,null,null,null,2537]
```

I'd like to stick with an iterative solution if possible.

Comment: what is the difference between 2 array you provided, looks like same to me?

Comment: I don't understand. Aren't the sample data lists not a trees? And @Narendra a `2461` was switched with a `2393` near the end.

Comment: @clabe45 They are arrays of the tree nodes' values. You can see the original question by searching by "same tree" in LeetCode.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mess up your test case?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to stick with an iterative solution?  A recursive solution -- which  matches the data structure more closely -- is *much* simpler.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I guess because the main purpose of this question is to understand how to do it iteratively, not just to solve it in whatever way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing only the left children of both trees OR the right children of both trees because you have `else if` there when comparing children. Remove the `else`. Because, if both `this.left` and `this.right` from both trees are not null, the right children will not be compared because you have `else` there. Only the left children are compared

```
    if(lastNodePair[0].left && lastNodePair[1].left) {
        nodes.push([lastNodePair[0].left, lastNodePair[1].left])   
    }
    if(lastNodePair[0].right && lastNodePair[1].right) {
        nodes.push([lastNodePair[0].right, lastNodePair[1].right])        
    }
```